# How to remove unsupported format podcasts from iTunes download queue on iPad/iPhone

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I tried download some video podcast episodes a few days ago but the iPad displayed a message saying it can't download them because they were in a format it couldn't read.

The problem is they are now still on the download queue in the iTunes app.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the iTunes 'Downloads' section, select and delete any downloads. Quit iTunes.

Look in your iTunes folder, where the audio files get stored. For example ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/. Here, you should find a 'Downloads' folder. Inside it, 'Podcasts' (assuming that the file you're downloading has the media type of podcast).

Inside here should be a folder with the name of the podcast subscription with '.tmp' appended. Inside here should be the partial file that you've downloaded. Trash the folder and its contents.

Restart iTunes. Note that iTunes can be a bit sticky when it comes to automatic downloads (e.g. I am asked to log in twice when launching iTunes). The actions above should result in there not being a 'Downloads' on the sidebar. If for some reason, there still is, select and delete the items there again.

---

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer but i was talking about the iPad iTunes app not the mac OSX application.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't read that part. On the iPad, in the Downloads tab of iTunes, if I swipe to the right on the podcast, it gives me the option to delete the download, similar to how you can delete an email message without viewing it. BTW, how did you get an unsupported file format in the iTunes app?